# how to launch bash in my newly made kernel?

Tags: c, kernel

I want to launch bash inside my kernel.

I have tried using system() but... I found out it's only really for little things. And not for kernel developing. And im stuck here at the moment...

```
void kernel_entry()
{
  init_vga(GREEN, BLACK);
  print_string("$ ");
  test_input();
```

where it says print_string I will replace it with the code to bring up bash. But I need help with that part...

Comment: well spawning new processes is done using syscalls like `fork` and `exec`, which are functions provided by the kernel. You ARE creating the kernel so you should implement the parts necessary for spawning a new process your self.

Comment: Also bash needs libc and other dynamically linked libraries, I guess your kernel will need to provide a dynamic linker as well

Comment: I guess what you should do is implement a little command line parser yourself in the kernel because using bash will be much much harder. Maybe at a later stage you can use bash but for now just do your own little thing.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Adam Zahran's answer:

In order to run a process from the kernel, you need to create a new process and then `execve("/bin/bash")`.

A reference would be:
`start_kernel()` -> `arch_call_rest_init()` -> `rest_init()` -> `kernel_init()` -> `try_to_run_init_process()` -> `run_init_process()`
all of which you can find [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/init/main.c).

Specifically bash, at least on Linux, is compiled as a dynamically-linked ELF binary (as is `/sbin/init`...)
So your kernel needs to be able to support the [ELF binary format and dynamic loading](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L685).

Needless to say, it also needs to support all the system calls that bash makes, you can run `bash` under `strace(1)` to see what system calls are used.